# spring thymeleaf combo box get selected value

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have this enum class,that has a set of values.
I display the values in a combo box. 
How do I get the selected values?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accountant")
public class Accountant {

    @Column(name="country")
    private String country;

    public enum country{
        MALAYSA,GREECE
    }
}
```

In the controller I have already set it by doing
`modelAndView.addObject("currentAccountant", loggedInUser);`

I list them all out by:

```
<form th:action="@{/updateAccountant}"  th:object="${currentAccountant}" class="form-inline"  method="post" id="companyProfileForm" name="companyProfileForm">

<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" style="width:300px;margin-left: 50px;"  >
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Please select a Country</option>
        <option th:each="country : ${T(Accountant.Country).values()}"
            th:value="${country}" 
            th:text="${country.getValue()}">
        </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

How do i get the selected value from the combo box in the form?
And later set back the value when the form is loaded.

I tried this, but nothing gets listed in the combo box.:

`<select th:field="*{country}" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">`

when i remove the `th:field="*{country}"` it displays the countries.
 `<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">`

Comment: And where is `th:object` ?? you have to use that in order to `th:field=*` systax to work

Comment: when i add th:field=*  to have  <select class="form-control selectpicker" th:field="*{currentAccountant.state}" data-live-search="true" style="width:300px;margin-left: 50px;"  >    the combo box is no longer populated

Comment: You didn not understand what I meant. *{} systax works with `th:object`. Read the thymeleaf documentation about forms.

Comment: yes, the th:object exists. Do see the latest full code posted. thanks   the values dont get poopulated

Comment: Now you are missing `th:field` on `select` did you read the docs? (I know u didnt)

Comment: After much time i hacked the solution, do see below and help verify my facts. thanks so much for helping out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this took me some while to resolve, hack the solution.

1. for the combo box, to get selected value , the `th:field` it should not be field name-column name variable  `country` . It should be the enum list name `Country`   Note the naming difference **capital C**
2. To get all values of the combo  box, you should do  `${T(com.workspez.model.Accountant.States).getSortedValue()}`  You need to specify **full package name**.